# disabling adjacent tabs using react hooks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

When I click item one button in first tab it should disable next two tabs.

When I click it back it should enable the other two tabs.

Same functionality should happen for other tabs.

Right now I disabled the second tab by using disabled property.

Can you guys tell me how to fix it.
Providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ulrv5

```or-tag-here
export default function SimpleTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  function handleChange(event, newValue) {
    setValue(newValue);
  }

  function selectButton(e) {
    //const selectedButton = e.currentTarget;
    const selectedButton = e.target;
    console.log("selectedButton--->", selectedButton);

    this.setState({ selectedButton: false });
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
          <Tab label="Item One" />
          <Tab label="Item Two" disabled />
          <Tab label="Item Three" />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      {value === 0 && (
        <TabContainer>
          Item One
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={selectButton}
          >
            item one
          </Button>
        </TabContainer>
      )}
      {value === 1 && (
        <TabContainer>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={selectButton}
          >
            item one
          </Button>
        </TabContainer>
      )}
      {value === 2 && (
        <TabContainer>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={selectButton}
          >
            item one
          </Button>
        </TabContainer>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `this.setState` doesn't exist in function components ...only in extended Component class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you basically need a boolean variable so click on the inner buttons will toggle it.

If so, like @charlietfl mention, you can't use `this.setState` in a function component but with `useState` you can set the state even though with the method (the 2nd argument) you get from `useState`.

So the solution will be to initialize the variable:

```
const [isDisabled, disableButtons] = React.useState(true);
```

Set conditional `disabled` attribute to the 2nd and 3rd tabs

```
<Tab label="Item Two" disabled={isDisabled} />
<Tab label="Item Three" disabled={isDisabled} />
```

And in the `selectButton()` function, toggle it

```js
function selectButton() {
  //const selectedButton = e.currentTarget;
  disableButtons(!isDisabled);
  // this.setState({ selectedButton: false });
}
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-x4gdm)

Comment: hey but when you click in second tab button its not disabling first first and second tab

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When you click on the button inside the second tab it should disable the first and the second tab?

Comment: yeah...similarly when we click first tab button it should disable second and third tabs

Comment: So just remove the disabled attribute from the first tab and add it on the third tab. If each button should disable different tabs, specify what is the wanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which would return a disabled text or empty string accordingly, and write `{this.getClass()}` instead of disabled according to condition